# Updating a database that contains USA and Canada information, with just Canada information

Tags: php, sql, database

Sorry if I don't explain properly.

I currently have a database containing entries for a funeral home, both with USA and Canada. That database has multiple different tables splitting up the data.

In one table called `funeralhome` I have an `ID` and `name` which contains the names of the funeralhomes. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGjK6.png)

Both USA and Canada are in this table.

In the next table called `funeralhome_address`, it contains 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cou1M.png)
    ID, funeralhome(id which links uniquely back to 'funeralhome' table),
    address(id links to address table)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdnLy.png),
    city(id which links to city table).

Like the `funeralhome` table, the `address` table has all the addresses for USA and Canada.

So now here's my question, is it possible/how would i go about updating this data with another separate table only containing canadian information without messing up the way these tables connect.

The new table i have contains 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h251n.png)
    id,funeralhomename,city,province,postal,phone.

I need to add `funeralhomename` to `funeralhome` and the rest of the data to address and still keep them all connected.

Comment: You are obviously new to Relational Databases. You dont need another table, you only need a query that only returns the Canadian information.

Comment: If you were to show us the schema for all these tables, or better still create a little SQLFiddle for us to play with, someone is bound to create a query for you

Comment: Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE TableName;` on all the relevant tables and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: Yes I am newer to Databases. I didn't create these databases, but I uploaded the new table which I showed from an excel sheet. I tried to embed some more images. I more or less have a solution to add the new table to the others, I was looking for clarification it wont mess with the id's if if update the new data in. Thank you.

Comment: Also the new table is new information, outdating the information in the usa/canada table. That's the reason why I need to update it.